# Scroll animation inside anchor links jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I am trying to make an scroll animation when someone access to an anchor link, like this:

```
www.miweb.com/section/#anchorLink
```

And I am doing it with this code, but there's something wrong in it because i can not execute anything else after it (alert("the end") in this case) in case a user access to the URL **with no anchor ID**.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$('[name="'+window.location.hash.replace("#", "")+'"]').offset().top
}, 500);

alert("the end");
```

If the user access from a URL with anchor ID, it will be executed.

How can i do to execute code after this function in any case?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have an element whose name attribute is *<anchorLink>* ?

Comment: That's an example :) But yeah, i have it. The real anchor link is just a number, and ID. Then i have in my code <a name="[ID]"></a> Anyway, it works well, but it just stops executing stuff located after that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to execute code **after** the animation, do like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$('[name="'+window.location.hash.replace("#", "")+'"]').offset().top
}, 500, function() {
    alert("the end");
});
```

**Update**:
After OP's comments, I think you are having javascript error accessing top property when offset() is null (which is the case when there's no anchor), so you guard against accesing that possible null reference, like so:

```
dest = $('[name="'+window.location.hash.replace("#", "")+'"]').offset();
dtop = dest != null ? dest.top : null;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: dtop
}, 500);

alert("the end");​
```

Now the `alert()` should print just fine.

You could easily spot similar errors like this in future if you look at the browser javascript console, I just did so and saw the error about the null reference.

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for. I want just to be able to still writing code after this one. Now, I can not because the code i write after it is like it didn't exist. Even just an "alert".

Comment: In that case you need to post the full code so we see the surrounding code on which you are executing that alert(), and tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, now i see. Things i write after it are only executed after an access with an anchor ID to the page. If there's no anchor id on the URL, the alert won't be launched. How can I do to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Think about in what event do you want your alert() to be executed upon.. Without seeing your code we cant tello you more, you can paste your code to http://pastie.org and put the link here.

Comment: There's no more code. The alert should be executed always. With anchor at the URL or without it. Once the animation has taken place, and when it can not take place because there's no anchor.

Comment: Think that instead of an Alert, i want to write 100 more functions for the rest of the site. Totally unrelated with this one.

Comment: I think I've spotted the error in your javascript that was stoping the execution. Javascript console will help you spot errors like this, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Nelson, That's what i wanted :)

Comment: This worked when I changed name to id in the dest var and excuted after page has loaded.